# Django, opencv, ошибка libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: django, opencv

Файл video.py работает при запуске из терминала без ошибок. Но при запуске из приложения Django вылетает следующая ошибка :

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Что это за ошибка и как избавиться?